# How to get the latest error details from the EventViewer log using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, event-viewer

I am using C# code to fetch the error message of a particular error from the eventviewer log file.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      EventLog myLog = new EventLog(); 
      myLog.Log = "Application";
      myLog.Source = "Application Error";
      foreach (System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry entry in myLog.Entries)
      {
         if (entry.TimeGenerated == DateTime.Parse("9/19/2016 11:48:58 AM"))
            {
               using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("Example.txt"))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(error_Message);
            }
       }
     }
```

This is my main function where I am getting the error message of a particular error in my Application log and I am printing the error message in a text file. So instead of accessing the error with the datetime, I want to access the latest error in the logfile.How can I get the last entered error in the logfile?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did not get why you are comaparing the timestamp when you want the last error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EventLog myLog = new EventLog(); 
myLog.Log = "Application";
myLog.Source = "Application Error";

var lastEntry = myLog.Entries[myLog.Entries.Count-1];
var last_error_Message = lastEntry.Message;

for(int index=myLog.Entries.Count-1; index>0;index--)
{
    var errLastEntry = myLog.Entries[index];
    if (errLastEntry.EntryType == EventLogEntryType.Error)
    {
        //this is the last entry with Error
        var appName = errLastEntry.Source;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.The answer works fine. But in the logfile, there are Information,Warnings, and Error.This code can capture the message for the last entry irrespective of the type, that is, warning,Informaton or error. How can I change the code to capture the Last ERROR Message alone even if the last entry was a warning or information.`var lastEntry = myLog.Source[myLog.Source.Count - 1];` will this work? But it shows me error

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That gave me the expected result